# Safely stopping Monero daemon sync (monerod)

Tags: monerod, blockchain, synchronization, monerod-commands

I finally got the blockchain syncinc good... I am just wondering if there is a special way to stop the blockchain sync so you can do it again later from where you stopped it?

last time I did this, it told me there was a BUS ERROR or something when I kept trying to restart it and when I deleted the lmdb folder and resync from scratch it worked so it seems like stopping in the middle and restarting it corrupted the blockchain maybe?

is there some safe way in linux to stop the blockchain sync before it downloads all blocks and restart later?

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to exit monerod is to use `exit`. Sending signal 15 (graceful exit) is also a canonical way to exit (for example if the process does not have a console). If it was started as a daemon (ie, with `--detach`), then sending the exit to the detached daemon is done this way: `monerod exit`.

monerod uses a database to store the blockchain, so *normally* it doesn't need anything special to save, as it should always be in a good state. However, an OS crash (or OS/filesystem bug) could cause some disk writes to be lost, causing corruption. monerod by default will use a "mostly safe" database mode, which may be vulnerable to such crashes, but is a lot faster. With the recent 0.11 release, monerod will use a hybrid approach, using the "fast" mode while doing the initial sync (where speed is more important), and switch to the safe method once synced. Therefore, after sync, you should not be able to lose data by database corruption. Note that, of course, if you have flaky hardware, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

The command `exit` will stop it gracefully.